# Stream any audio to DLNA/UPNP speakers

Tags: audio, speaker, dlna

Is there a generic ways how to stream *any* audio from my mobile or table to my WiFi DLNA/UPnP speakers? By any audio I mean any audio output from any application - YouTube, Audible, BeyondPod, any music player etc.

I figured out partial solution for [BeyondPod](http://www.beyondpod.mobi), a podcast client, and [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp), where BubbleUPnP streams to the speaker when it is set as "external" player for BeyondPod. It's a partial solution because it works only for applications with support for redirection to external player. YouTube or Audible has no option to use external player.

And it is not ideal solution either. For example playlists are tricky, both BubbleUPnP and BeyondPod have their own playlists and they don't play along well. BubbleUPnP is unfortunately not just just audio *forwarder*, it's full fledged media player and its own broad functionality in this scenario it gets in the way :(

Is there a proper audio forwarding (re-streaming, re-directing) solution, an app or a driver, which would take any audio output and forward it to my external speakers? My speakers support UPnP/DLNA, Airplay and Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

The only app I know that streams the entire audio output of your phone is [AirAudio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.airaudio). It is capable of streaming to UPnP/DLNA speakers but does also support AirPlay.

It does require root privileges, though.

Comment: Looks promising. I haven't so far rooted my device but when I do I'll give it a shot. Thinking about it, forwarding all audio probably would require root. So far I'm stuck with bluetooth solution.

Comment: airaudio requires a license