# Stream Audible audio to DLNA/UPNP speakers

Tags: audio, dlna, audible

I would like to listen to my [Audible audio books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audible.application) on external speakers because the tablet's internal speakers are too weak and headphones are not always practical.

In another my post, [Stream any audio to DLNA/UPNP speakers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190837/stream-any-audio-to-dlna-upnp-speakers), I asked if there is a generic solution to stream audio output from any app on my Android devices, if there is no generic solution then have anyone figured out a specific solution for Audible?

Audible doesn't seem to support external players, so I cannot use [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) like I can with [BeyondPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.beyondpod) for free podcasts.

I have nice external speakers, Panasonic SC-NE5DBEB-K by the way. When I am home, my tablet and speakers are on the same home wireless network, I would like to listen to Audible when doing household chores for example, but the tablets internal speakers are too weak, I have to move around the house, it sometimes noisy and headphones are not practical, I still need to hear other people too.

Answer (score 1):

So I got official response from Audible team:

It's Bluetooth, Auxiliary Input (audio jack, ie wired speakers) or ..burn a CD!

UPnP/DLNA - not mentioned.

So it's Bluetooth I guess for me. Not the preferred option :(

For for completeness' sake, here is precise citation from Audible Customer Service team email:

> Bluetooth
>   If your mobile device and speaker support Bluetooth, your audiobook's will play through your speakers similar to how a phone call comes through via Bluetooth. The Audible app must be open and all functionality for the audiobook (changing chapters, narration speed, playing, pausing, etc.) can only be changed through the Audible app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you download your Audible purchases to iTunes (which can decrypt Audible files) your desktop, then you can send the audio from your computer to the unpnp renderer. At least it works on a Mac.